# SVG circle starting point

Tags: javascript, css, svg, rotation, geometry

How can I change the starting point of a svg circle for animate it progressively begining at 0 o'clock? the default circle svg begin at 3 o'clock.

My current circle ( hover for animation):

```css
#timeline{
 position:fixed;
 width:500px;
 height:500px;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 margin-top:-250px;
 margin-left:-250px;
 overflow:hidden;
 pointer-events: all;
 z-index:99999;
}

#bluecircle{
 stroke-dasharray:1510;
 stroke-dashoffset:1510;
 -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
 transition:all 1s ease;
}


#bluecircle:hover{
 stroke-dashoffset:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="timeline">
  
  <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    
    <circle id="greycircle" fill="none" stroke="#727272" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="249.85" cy="248.065" r="239.024"/>
    
    <circle id="bluecircle" fill="none" stroke="#2C75FF" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="249.85" cy="248.065" r="239.024"/>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rotate the circle with a transformation?

```css
#timeline{
 position:fixed;
 width:500px;
 height:500px;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 margin-top:-250px;
 margin-left:-250px;
 overflow:hidden;
 pointer-events: all;
 z-index:99999;
}

#bluecircle{
 stroke-dasharray:1510;
 stroke-dashoffset:1510;
 -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
 transition:all 1s ease;
}


#bluecircle:hover{
 stroke-dashoffset:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="timeline">

<svg x="0px" y="0px" width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <circle id="greycircle" fill="none" stroke="#727272" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="249.85" cy="248.065" r="239.024"/>
    
    <circle id="bluecircle" fill="none" stroke="#2C75FF" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="249.85" cy="248.065" r="239.024" transform="rotate(-90 249.85 248.065)"/>
</svg>
```

Edit: Updated with CSS

Comment: any idea how to make the animation play progressively on scroll ? actually i  have 4 section so i just want that in section2 the blue circle at 25%, section3=50% section4=75% ... i use a full page js script that make each section at 100% of the window so the body is in overflow hidden

Comment: @user2994359 can you explain the reasoning behind using dash-dashoffset?

Comment: Make sure you test on iOS devices as well as desktop. Some start rendering circles at 0300 as per the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#CircleElement , but some (ios) devices start at 1200. Solution: use two semicircular arcs in a path instead of a circle.