# Radial Animation differs from desktop to mobile

Tags: javascript, ios, css, animation, svg

I just started working with SVG in the last couple days and I've built a simple radial animation for a pomodoro application. I've come to find that the starting point of the animation differs from what I have it set to and see on a desktop browser (0 deg). The below screenshot from my iPhone 6 in Safari shows what I am seeing (same result in Chrome and Firefox as well). You can see this live for yourself [here](https://blindfold-em.now.sh).

The circle's initial start path was at 90 deg so I applied the following to get the desired starting point:

```
<circle className={className} transform="rotate(-90, 50, 60)">
```

I've spent the morning searching through posts and the only thing I really found related to what I'm seeing is a comment at the bottom of this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29068366/6520579). I went to the spec and read up on it, but I'm not really understanding if I am better off drawing the circle using `path` or this semi-circle idea that was purposed in the comment (which I'm not understanding at all). It's my understanding now that in the mobile browsers however `<circle />` is interpreted the initial starting point is different than in a desktop browser (maybe I'm wrong and this is a OS related issue?).

Can anyone explain how to solve this? I'm not looking to have my problem solved by someone, just a nudge in the right direction. I've been reading through posts and googling for the last 2 hours with no luck and not much more understanding of the problem at large. Thank you in advance for your help.

[image: Initial Starting point in Safari on iOS]

Full Code for the `<circle />`:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import { styles } from '../../lib'

/**
 * @function Circle
 * @description renders <circle /> that is conditionally animated.
 *
 * @prop {String} className
 * @prop {Number} duration - desired length of timer formatted to seconds
 * @returns React Element
 */
 const Circle = ({ className, duration }) => (
  <circle className={className} transform="rotate(-90, 50, 60)">
    <style jsx>{`
      circle {
        cx: 50;
        cy: 60;
        fill: transparent;
        r: 35;
        stroke-width: 4;
      }
      .outer {
        stroke: ${styles.colors.highLight};
      }
      .overlay {
        stroke: none;
        stroke-dasharray: 219; /* NOTE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33922201/6520579 */
        stroke-linecap: round;
      }
      .cooldownAnimation {
        animation: ${duration}s linear normal forwards cooldown;
        stroke: ${styles.colors.text};
      }
     .timerAnimation {
        -webkit-animation: ${duration}s linear normal forwards timer;
        animation: ${duration}s linear normal forwards timer;
        stroke: ${styles.colors.text};
      }
      @-webkit-keyframes timer {
        from {
          stroke-dashoffset: 219;
        }
        to {
          stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        }
      }
      @keyframes timer {
        from {
          stroke-dashoffset: 219;
        }
        to {
          stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        }
      }
      @-webkit-keyframes cooldown {
        from {
         stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        }
        to {
         stroke-dashoffset: 219;
        }
      }
      @keyframes cooldown {
        from {
         stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        }
        to {
         stroke-dashoffset: 219;
        }
      }
      @media (orientation: landscape) {
        circle {
          r: 50;
        }
        .overlay {
          stroke-dasharray: 314;
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes timer {
          from {
           stroke-dashoffset: 314;
          }
          to {
           stroke-dashoffset: 0;
          }
        }
        @keyframes timer {
          from {
            stroke-dashoffset: 314;
          }
          to {
            stroke-dashoffset: 0;
          }
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes cooldown {
          from {
            stroke-dashoffset: 0;
          }
          to {
            stroke-dashoffset: 314;
          }
        }
        @keyframes cooldown {
          from {
            stroke-dashoffset: 0;
          }
          to {
            stroke-dashoffset: 314;
          }
        }
       }
    `}</style>
   </circle>
)

Circle.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string,
  duration: PropTypes.number
}

export default Circle
```

Comment: Dont know if this could have an effect https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/CoordinateSystem.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems I have fixed the issue and that it was two-fold:

1. It was in part to how I was writing the CSS. I normally work in Chrome and it didn't cause a fuss over what I was doing; however, after looking in the FireFox dev-tools and seeing that my `<circle />` and animation of the stroke was not even visible I found out that...

this code is not valid:

```
circle {
  cx: 50; /* NOT VALID */
  cy: 60; /* NOT VALID */
  fill: transparent;
  r: 35;  /* NOT VALID */
  stroke-width: 4;
}
```

These attributes **MUST** be passed on the element:

```
<circle
  className={className}
  cx="50"
  cy="60"
  r="35"
  transform="rotate(-90, 50, 60)"
>
```

2. After reading through comments of this [article](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/) and finding this [pen](https://codepen.io/AmeliaBR/pen/whcjq) I found out that I did not *need* to be using `stroke-dashoffset` and could instead use only `stroke-dasharray`; but instead of writing in shorthand:

shorthand method:

```
.overlay {
  stroke: none;
  stroke-dasharray: 219; /* Set both length of stroke & gap to 219px */
  stroke-linecap: round;
}
```

longhand method:

```
.overlay {
  stroke: none;
  stroke-dasharray: 0 219; /* Set stroke length to 0px & gap length to 219px */
  stroke-linecap: round;
}
```

Now in the `@keyframes` I just had to switch to `stroke-dasharray` and travel from no stroke length to a length of the entire circumference of the circle and visa versa for the the reverse animation.

```
@keyframes timer {
  from {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 219;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dasharray: 219 0;
  }
}
```

In doing this the animation is now functioning as desired across Chrome, FireFox, & Safari on both my iPhone 6 & iPad mini 4. I have no non-Apple devices to test this further unfortunately. I hope this can help out the next guy or gal who runs into this issue, Happy Coding!